# java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase-default.xml file seems to be for and old version of HBase (0.95.2-hadoop2), this version is 0.95.2-hadoop1

Tags: hbase

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import java.io.*;
public class createtable {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

          Configuration con = HBaseConfiguration.create();
          HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(con);
          HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new
          HTableDescriptor("emp");

          tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("personal"));
          tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("professional"));
          admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
          System.out.println(" Table created ");
       }
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: hbase-default.xml file seems to be for and old version of HBase (0.95.2-hadoop2), this version is 0.95.2-hadoop1

I am using eclipse java project and also added jar files :
hbase-client-0.95.0.jar ,
hbase-common-0.95.2-hadoop1.jar ,
hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar ,
protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar ,
hbase-protocol-0.95.0.jar ,
commons-logging-1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question. It is currently not possible to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hbase/0.99.2_2/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration.java), lines 66-75.